# Не понятно, как работает свойство min-height в CSS

Tags: css

Справочник: min-height задаёт минимальную высоту элемента.
Можно ли объяснить, на что влияет данное свойство? Если экран сузить меньше указанной величины ничего не происходит визуально. Объясните, пож-ста.

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css/min-height

Comment: @soledar10 давайте не давать ссылок на устаревшие ресурсы, https://webref.ru/css/min-height

Comment: ну и что. Задаем этой картинке(в примере по ссылке) min-height: 80 px, сжимаем экран до 50 и ничего не происходит. И что?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Допустим у вас на странице ряд изображений, вы им задаете высоту height:auto; и ограничение не меньше 40px min-height:40px; и все изображения если они разной высоты будут разной высоты, но с ограничением не меньше 40px.

Если вам нужно задать процентное ограничение по высоте, то в таком случае высота родительского блока должна быть задана явно.

Это свойство не явное задание высоты, а ограничение на высоту.
Это свойство можно применять к блокам, инлайн блокам.

Comment: И Вам большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если вы берете проценты, их нужно брать от чего то
Т.е. либо пропишите:

```
body, html{height:100%}
```

Либо укажите в родительском элементе тоже самое:

```
body.style_body { height:100%}
```

Тогда min-height прекрасно работает.